# Why is the UWP app to app communication using socket works only in Windows 10 PC but not in Windows 10 Phone?

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

I am in need of UWP app to app communication using Socket on the same machine. The link "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets" states that,
Note As part of network isolation, the system forbids establishing socket connections (Sockets or WinSock) between two UWP apps running on the same machine via either the local loopback address (127.0.0.0) or explicitly specifying the local IP address. This means that you cannot use sockets to communicate between two UWP apps. UWP supplies other mechanisms for communicating between apps.

I have done my implementation as follows.

- Created an app service which will start a UDP Socket listener.
- Included this app service in an application which is called service provider.
- Service Provider starts the app service which in turn create a UDP Socket listener.
- Once the listener started, service provider itself create a UDP client and launches the second application.
- Second application creates another UDP client and starts communicate to listener created by app service.

This works for me in Windows 10 PC (no problem at all). But in Windows Phone 10, it works only when I run it in debug mode from Visual Studio. But when I run the Service Provider in Windows Phone 10 (not in debug mode from Visual Studio), the communication between listener and the service provider client works well. If I launch the second application (service provider launches it successfully) then communication between second application's client and listener is not working and even it stops the existing connection between listener and the service provider client. I couldn't able to debug it as it is working without problem in debug mode.

Comment: Have you declare the server capability at your app's packagemanifest? As of your description, it seems that 'privateNetworkClientServer' and/or 'internetClientServer' capabilities are required, I believe.  For details, refer the following link.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

Comment: @pnp0a03: Yes. I have declared both capabilities. As per Microsoft comment, we cannot use sockets to communicate between two UWP apps on the same machine. I wonder why it works in PC but not in Phone.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/suspend-an-app. Visual Studio prevents Windows from suspending an app that is attached to the debugger. This is the reason socket communication kept alive when i run Windows Phone app from Visual Studio debugger. When I call suspend event by clicking Suspend icon from Debug Location the communication lost as the application goes to background.

Comment: The limitation of app to app communication doesn't apply to apps in the same process. So when you create the server and client app from the same service the two will be able to communicate (not regarding the debug mode issues, anyway).